# Python Pandas - Merge different sized DataFrames and replace value in row with matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of a format similar to below:

df1:

```
0  fname    lname    note
1  abby     ross     note1
2  rob      william  note2
3  abby     ross     note3
4  john     doe      note4
5  bob      dole     note5
```

df2:

```
0  fname    lname    note
1  abby     ross     note6
2  rob      william  note4
```

I want to merge finding matches based on fname and lname and then update the note column in the first DataFrame with the note column in the second DataFrame

The result I am trying to achieve would be like this:

```
0  fname    lname    note
1  abby     ross     note6
2  rob      william  note4
3  abby     ross     note6
4  john     doe      note4
5  bob      dole     note5
```

This is the code I was working with so far:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['fname', 'lname'], how='left')
```

but it just creates a new column with _y appended to it. How can I get it to just update that column?

Any help would be greatly appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Hey, deleted the comment because yes, I saw the problem with what I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge and then correct the values:

```
df_3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['fname', 'lname'], how='outer') 

df_3['note'] = df_3['note_x']
df_3.loc[df_3['note'].isna(), 'note'] = df_3['note_y']
df_3 = df_3.drop(['note_x', 'note_y'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do what you are doing:

then:

```
# fill nan values in note_y
out_df['note_y'].fillna(out_df['note_x'])

# Keep cols you want
out_df = out_df[['fname', 'lname', 'note_y']]

# rename the columns
out_df.columns = ['fname', 'lname', 'note']
```

I don't like this approach a whole lot as it won't be very scalable or generalize able. Waiting for a stellar answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with update

```
df1=df1.set_index(['fname','lname'])
df1.update(df2.set_index(['fname','lname']))
df1=df1.reset_index()
df1
Out[55]: 
  fname    lname    0   note
0  abby     ross  1.0  note6
1   rob  william  2.0  note4
2  john      doe  3.0  note3
3   bob     dole  4.0  note4
```